# Escaping in groovy

Tags: groovy, escaping

I  need a help in escaping in groovy

I have some string in text file like this **#$commonTomcat620.max_threads$#**  These value i have to replace in runTime.

I used following code:

```
    def str = "#\$commonTomcat620.max_threads\$#"
    fileContents = fileContents.replaceAll("${str}","100");
```

This str is printin the values as #$commonTomcat620.max_threads$#. but not replacing in file. I tried withOut #$ . it is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a couple of options to escape the dollar sign:

This works (with dollar-slashy strings):

```
def str = $/#\$$commonTomcat620.max_threads\$$#/$
```

Or this (with single quote strings):

```
def str = '#\\$commonTomcat620.max_threads\\$#'
```

Other options probably exist too